# Prometheus in Grafana set a minimum threshold for query

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, grafana

I am configuring Grafana using Prometheus queries

I would like to limit lists of results on all pods that are over 30% or to top 50

This is my query

```
sum(rate(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{container_name!="POD",pod_name!=""}[5m])) by (pod_name)
```

How can I add some comparison for this sum to be larger then 0.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For "greater-than" queries:

```
sum(rate(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{container_name!="POD",pod_name!=""}[5m])) by (pod_name) > 0.3
```

For top 50 queries:

```
topk(50, sum(rate(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{container_name!="POD",pod_name!=""}[5m])) by (pod_name))
```